# Run background location updates in ViewController or separate object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

What is the best practice for doing background-location updates?

Should the `delegate` of the `CLLocationManager` be the `ViewController` it was activated, or should I create a separate object and perform all the logic there? In that case, what kind of object/ subclass should I create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For background location updates your app may not be running at the time the update is generated. If you've been terminated then you may be re-launched as a result of the location update.

In that case your app delegate is probably the best candidate for the location manager delegate. You can set up your app delegate to pass the information to whatever objects need to be notified.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Just a quick follow-up: How would I tell the `AppDelegate` to start updating the location?